# Popular references for good UI site design for corporate intranets

Tags: user-interface, intranet

I have trawled for info about corporate intranet designs and layouts and they seem to be hard to find.

My requirements are simple, a box or table based interface with good usage of fonts and colours that is low maintenance and has high compatibility across A grade browsers. As I am not a designer, I don't know how to identify good combinations of layouts, fonts and colours. But like many, know a good layout when I see it.

Exotic is not required. This has to be easy to maintain. So, if anyone can reference a decent site that has good examples of clean and simple intranets that use CSS or tables for layouts that would be appreciated. Prefer to avoid designs that have hacks and/or onload javascript "magic". No animation! No Flash!

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for ease of use and simplicity of design check out the site's linked in:
http://www.djangoproject.com/
This is a simple framework to use and the site's it creates tend to be very simple and clean. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it's not quite what I was looking for. I'll try and be a bit more specific. A set of CSS/JS/Resource libraries that give you a simple layout with a few styles and colour themes. YUI is an example, but has very limited styles, it also doesn't provide a few easy to use themes.